# Можно ли экспортировать дизайн в Figma, если доступ view-only?

Tags: figma

20 макетов вручную муторно скачивать. Подскажите пожалуйста
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать, если скачивать муторно?

Answer (score 1):

Просто создайте свою копию и делайте в ней что хотите:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доступ `view-only` предоставляет экспорт элементов, но не редактирование их.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Как я сразу не догадалась!

Comment: @AnkudinovaPolina если ответ Вам помог, отметьте его решением